# How to convert string values into numbers and booleans from an object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, serialization

For exmaple if I have a JavaScript Object like,

```js
{
    id: "234",
    name: "shreyas",
    active: "true"
}
```

How can I convert it to like this

```js
{
    id: 234,
    name: "shreyas",
    active: true
}
```

Basically removing `""` (double quotes) from numbers and booleans.

I managed to remove booleans

```js
let query = JSON.stringify(req.query);
query.replace(/"true"/g, `true`).replace(/"false"/g, `false`);
query = JSON.parse(query)
```

How can I do the same but with numbers?

What I tried so far:

```js
const nums = query.match(/"\d+"/g);
        
nums?.forEach((num) => {
            
    const newNum = parseInt(num)

    query.replace(`${num}`, `'${newNum}'`);
});
```

Comment: I think `parseInt()` should fix your problem

Comment: IKR, but how would I find numbers with double quotes, and replace the them without qoutes with same values? ```const nums = query.match(/"\d+"/g);
  
  nums?.forEach((num) => {
   
            const newNum = parseInt(num)

   query.replace(`${num}`, `'${newNum}'`);
  }); ```

Comment: Why don't we get to the root of the problem instead? Where do these objects come from? What code is responsible for adding these numeric and boolean properties as strings?

Comment: That's from my API's query parameters. That's a good point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue i have faced with my `process.env`. So i created `parser` function for type clear parsed output

1. we need to  pre-declare the false and true values in array
2. Then return the value inside the loop depend on matched array condition
3. `isNaN(Number(str))` its only accept the pure number. Allowed like this `"292"` not `a233`
4. Additionaly you could create the array from string `one,two,three` => `["one","two","three"]`

```js
const obj = { id: "234", name: "shreyas", active: "true",arr:"one,two,three" }


 const clean = (value = '') => {
    let FALSY_VALUES = ['', 'null', 'false', 'undefined'];
    let TRUE_VALUES = ["true"];
    if (!value || FALSY_VALUES.includes(value)) {
        return false;
    }else if (!value || TRUE_VALUES.includes(value)) {
        return true;
    } else if (!isNaN(Number(value))) {
        return Number(value);
    } else if (value.match(',')) {
        return value.split(',').map((a) => a.trim());
    }
    return value;
};

 const parser = (a)=> {
    let env = {};
    for (const k in a) {
        env[k] = clean(a[k]);
    }
    return env;
};


console.log(parser(obj))
```

Comment: Thanks prasanth! This is great! Exactly what I was looking for. I hope in future JavaScript has this inbuilt. : )

Answer (score 0):

My code is not perfect, but I hope it can help a little though

```js
let blah = {
    id: "234",
    age: "44",
    name: "shreyas",
    active: "true",
    isActive: "false"
};

console.log(converting(blah));

function converting(obj) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);

  for (let key of keys) {
    // convert to int
    if (parseInt(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = parseInt(obj[key]);
    }
    // convert to boolean
    if (String(obj[key]).toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true' ||
    String(obj[key]).toLocaleLowerCase() === 'false') {
      obj[key] = String(obj[key]).toLocaleLowerCase() === 'true';
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested objects:

```js
function isObject(data: any): Boolean {
  return data && data.constructor === Object;
}

function parseNumbersAndBooleans(data: any): object {
  const newObject = Object.assign({}, data);

  for (const key in data) {
    const value = newObject[key];

    if (!isNaN(Number(value))) {
      newObject[key] = Number(value);
    } else if (["true", "false"].includes(value)) {
      newObject[key] = JSON.parse(value);
    } else if (isObject(value)) {
      newObject[key] = parseNumbersAndBooleans(value);
    }
  }

  return newObject;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).